# Creating a Dropdown menu in Drupal 7

Tags: routes, navigation

My question is how do we get the menu in drop down structure. 
i.e

```
<ul><li><a></a><ul><li><a></a></li></ul></li></ul>
```

I used following:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => $main_menu)); ?>
```

but this only produces top level menu even if we have sub menus in menu management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

horizontal or vertical nested menus: [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) or [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish)

simple vertical nested menus: [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)