# Drupal 7 Bartik theme drop down menu

Tags: theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drop down menu in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/drop-down-menu-in-drupal-7)

How can I add the drop down menu item to the navigation menu in the Bartik theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can able to do it using [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module. Check [here](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-18-create-drop-down-menus-drupal-7-using-nice-menus-module) for detailed step by step tutorial on how to use nice menus module.

> Nice Menus enables drop-down/right/left expandable menus. It uses only
>   CSS for most browsers, with minimal Javascript for IE6. (Version 2
>   uses the Superfish jQuery plugin for all browsers, with an option to
>   disable JS, and falls back to CSS-only for browsers that can handle
>   it.)